# Active Admin: A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a simple rails app i had added Active Admin onit, and it worked fine (except that my css is having some problem) but suddenly i started reciving this error just after i tried doing some changes to the dashboard.rb file:

**This is the error:**

```
[2016-02-16T18:56:55.902056 #5260] FATAL -- :
ArgumentError (A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module
tree but is still active!):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:26:in `notification'
```

**my application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation
  before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: proc { user_signed_in? }
  before_action :notification, if: proc { user_signed_in? }
  private

  def mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

  def conversation
    @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_last_seen_at
    current_user.update_attribute(:last_seen_at, Time.now)
  end

  def notification
    @shipment_ids = Shipment.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:id)
    @comment = Comment.where("shipment_id IN (?)", @shipment_ids).where(:is_read => false).where.not(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after making the changes?

Comment: Have you tried `spring stop`?

Comment: what's that i don't anything about it @jvillian

Comment: From the github page: "Spring is a Rails application preloader. It speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background so you don't need to boot it every time you run a test, rake task or migration." Sometimes, when I'm having problems that may have to do with the preloading, I type `spring stop` at the command line in the root of your project directory (which will stop spring). Spring will restart next time you do `rails c` at the console, although not for tests. It's just part of making sure your rails app is doing a full, clean start.